# Cloudfoundry Login Issues

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry, vmc

I just signed up for an account with cloudfoundry and received a confirmation email with password.

After installing vmc, I vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com and that verifies.

Then I tried to sign-in using $vmc login but get this error.

```
**source '<oauth><error_descri' not in JSON!, try again or register for an account**
```

So, i reset my password multiple times but still receive the same error. Also the password doesn't work on the website where I want to dl micro cloud foundry.

Anyone know why?

**Update** Used a different email and connected fine. Strange.

Comment: If you could share the email that failed by opening a private ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com, it would be helpful in identifying the root cause of this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra **-t** option to the end of the vmc login command. That will show you request/response headers and the response json as well.